# Change a PHP array into separate strings

Tags: php, arrays, pdo

I have an array returned from sql and I need to get them into separate strings to use on the page. It is out of a single row in the database and lists all the folders a user has.
example in database john has a red folder, green folder, blue folder. 
I run the query and use fetchAll to return john's folders. I have it in an array. I can echo the array and it outputs redfoldergreenfolderbluefolder

How can I take the array and split it into separate strings?

PHP code

```
  $query = "SELECT album_name FROM albums WHERE username = :username";
    $query_params = array(
    ':username' => $email
    );

    try {
        $stmt   = $db->prepare($query);
        $result = $stmt->execute($query_params);
    }
    catch (PDOException $ex) {
        echo 'Database Error, please try again.';
    }

    $rows = $stmt->fetchAll();

    foreach ($rows as $row) {
    $post             = array();
    $post["album_name"] = $row["album_name"];
    echo $post["album_name"];  // This just lists all albums together no spaces or commas

    }

    $text = implode(",", $post);
    echo $text;  // This just outputs the last item (bluefolder)
```

Comment: echo $text; ?? ..is that instead of echo $post;?

Comment: wow can't believe I did that.  Edited code but now echo $text only outputs the last item in the array (bluefolder)

Comment: `echo $post` would throw  an `Array to string conversion` Error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below needs correction :

```
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    $post             = array();
    $post["album_name"] = $row["album_name"];
    echo $post["album_name"];  // This just lists all albums together no spaces or commas

}

$text = implode(",", $post);
echo $text;  // This just outputs the last item (bluefolder)
```

Change the above to :

```
$post = array();
foreach( $rows as $row )
{
//  $post = array(); // This line should not be here . It should be outside and above foreach
//  The below echo is for test purpose . Comment it if you don't need it
    echo $row["album_name"] ,' ';
//  $post["album_name"] = $row["album_name"]; // This keeps assigning $row["album_name"] to same index "album_name" of $post . Eventually you will have only one value in $post
    $post[] = $row["album_name"];
}

// $text = implode(",", $post); // With coma's as separator
$text = implode(" ", $post); // With blank's as separator
echo 'John has ' , $text;
```

Comment: ok using the code as you have above seems to be getting close or I just don't get it....  My output is
redfolder greenfolder bluefolder redfolder,greenfolder,bluefolder

It looks like the echo $row["album_name"] ,' '; gave it a space between the items and the implode call below added commas.  Here is my dumb question.  How do I use these strings? user John has $string1 $string2 and $string3   Thanks for the help on this.

Comment: Try changing `$text = implode(",", $post); echo $text` to `$text = implode(" ", $post); echo 'John has ' ,$text;`

Comment: Marking this as accepted answer. Thanks for all of the help.  I actually need to use each string in separate queries to another database. I need to research how to call them.  Eventually need to do    $query = "SELECT photos FROM pictures WHERE folder = :bluefolder";

Comment: No problem . To access the items in $post individually , you could access as `$post[0]` , `$post[1]` etc . Ex. `echo $post[0];` .

Answer (score 0):

try `print_r($post);` on your last line.

Comment: using print_r($post) returned
Array ( [album_name] => bluefolder )

Answer (score 0):

The reason why it only show the last folder is because you do "$post = array()" at the beginning of your loop. It reset the array everytime... just take it out of the loop and put it above the foreach.

[1](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.phpplode.php): http://php.net/manual/en/function.imThe reason why it only show the last folder is because you do "$post = array()" at the beginning of your loop. It reset the array everytime... just take it out of the loop and put it above the foreach.

EDIT:

Try it this way :

```
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$post = array();

foreach ($rows as $key => $folder) {
    array_push($post, $folder)
}

$text = implode(",", $post);
```

Comment: Thanks, I moved the $post=array() above the foreach loop but still have the same output. Still not working but I believe this was a big part of it though. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

please use print_r($text) in side the for each and then you will get all the arry with commos
and remove $post = arry from there and put above of foreach.
i am trying to help you,may this help

thanks 
anand

Comment: I moved the print_r into the foreach loop, moved the $post= array() above and it now outputs 
Array ( [album_name] => redfolder ) Array ( [album_name] => greenfolder ) Array ( [album_name] => bluefolder )

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$post  = array();
foreach ($rows as $row) {

array_push($post, 'album_name', $row["album_name"]);

}

$text = implode(",", $post);
echo $text;
```

No assoc ver:

```
$post  = array();
foreach ($rows as $row) {

$post[] = $row["album_name"];

}

$text = implode(",", $post);
echo $text;
```